# How do i http request post/get to a link?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

I can't figure out how to do a http request to a link. I am try to post to a google apps script with the link below. I hope the link helps you because i can't really explain what i am trying to do. I just want to be able to run the google script which is possible with the link below. (I used it on a Node.JS application before.) So i want to be able to execute the link below thru Javascript. (JavaFX for my application.)

`String ScriptUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/" + ScriptID + "/exec?sheet=TestSheet&key=" + EnteredPlayerName + "&value=" + SelectedItemName;`

(What the google script does is: It takes the key (which is in the link) and makes a new row in a spreadsheet. In this row i creates a column with the value (which is in the link).

**Google Script:**

````
function doGet(e) {
    try {
        var key = e.parameter["key"]
        var sheetName = e.parameter["sheet"]
        var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
        var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(e.parameter["sheet"]);
        var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
        var value
        for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i][0] == key) {
                value = data[i][1];
            }
        }
        if (value) {
            return ContentService
                .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
                    "result": "success",
                    "value": value
                }))
                .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
        } else {
            return ContentService
                .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
                    "result": "error",
                    "error": "Key not found"
                }))
                .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        return ContentService
            .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
                "result": "error",
                "error": "Database does not exist"
            }))
            .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    }
}

function doPost(e) {
    var sheetNom = e.parameter["sheet"];
    var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
    lock.waitLock(30000);
    try {
        var key = e.parameter["key"]
        var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
        var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(e.parameter["sheet"]);
        var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
        var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
        var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
        var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
        var row = [];
        for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i][0] == e.parameter["key"]) {
                nextRow = i + 1;
            }
        }
        for (i in headers) {
            row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
        }
        sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
        return ContentService
            .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
                "result": "success",
                "row": nextRow
            }))
            .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    } catch (e) {
        return ContentService
            .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
                "result": "error",
                "error": e,
                "test": "Test",
                "sheet": sheetNom
            }))
            .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    } finally {
        lock.releaseLock();
    }
}

function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}```
````

Comment: Read about how to make http request in node here: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request/

Comment: Sorry i explained it wrong. I want to execute it in Javascript. (For my JavaFX application)

Comment: You want to get javascript from a URL, then run it?

Comment: No its hard to explain. I want to be able to post to the url. The google script should handle the rest. (In my node.js app i used: Axios.Post(ScriptUrl).) Maybe you know a similar way for Java

Comment: You want to run the Google Apps Script by requesting from Javascript to the Web Apps created by Google Apps Script. I understood like this. If my understanding is correct, can you provide the Google Apps Script? And also, can we think that your Google Apps Script works without the error?

Comment: That is exaclty what i want to do you understand me. The google app script works completely. As i said before i before i ran the script thru a Node.JS application (Discord Bot). I edited my question so it has the google app script in it.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers provide an `XMLHttpRequest` object which can be used to make HTTP requests from JavaScript:

```js
function httpGet(ScriptUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", ScriptUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

A tip: Synchronous requests are discouraged and will generate a warning along the lines. You should ideally not be using synchronous requests.

You should make an asynchronous request and handle the response inside an event handler.

```js
function httpGetAsync(ScriptUrl, callback)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", ScriptUrl, true); // true for asynchronous 
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. This works for HTML javascript right? Thats not what i need i explained it wrong i edited my question. (I need it for Javascript (JavaFX for my application))

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it! For the people that are interested how i did it here is the code:

```
String ScriptUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/exec?sheet=TestSheet&";
                String post_data = "key=" + EnteredPlayerName  + "&value=" + SelectedItemName;
                
                try {
                    
                    URL url = new URL(ScriptUrl);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    
                    OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                    outputStream.write(post_data.getBytes());
                    outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();
                    
                    String line= "";
                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                    
                    while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                        response.append(line);
                    }
                    
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    System.out.println("Response: " + response.toString());
                    
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Error in sending request.");
                }
```